# More action links in single wallpost

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to create wallpost with more than one action link?

My code works only with one action link. Wallpost with two action links is not sent to Facebook  (no error message).

```
var publish = {
    method : 'feed',
    name : name,
    link : link,
    picture : picture,
    caption : caption,
    description : description,
    message : message,
    actions : [{
        name : 'Link 1',
        link : 'http://www.example.com'
        },{
        name : 'Link 2',
        link : 'http://www.example2.com'
        }]   
};

FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a [response from Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/196482347101715) and you really **can not add more than one action link**.

Correct code for adding one link is:

```
var publish = {
    // ....
    actions : {
        name : 'Some Action Link!',
        link : 'http://www.example.com'
        }
};
```

Comment: I had the same problem. But actions field got deprecated on July 2015 anyway :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/, the `action_links` parameter is a "JSON-encoded array of action link objects, containing the link text and a hyperlink."

It looks like you're calling it `actions`, not `action_links`. Try this instead:

```
var publish = {
    method : 'feed',
    name : name,
    link : link,
    picture : picture,
    caption : caption,
    description : description,
    message : message,
    action_links : [{
        name : 'Link 1',
        link : 'http://www.example.com'
        },{
        name : 'Link 2',
        link : 'http://www.example2.com'
        }]   
};
```

Comment: I tried your solution and unfortunately does not work. Post is sent without action links.

I use FB.api to send post: [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

"**action:** A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action)"

I found this post: [http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/321](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/321) and there is written:

"(...) Going forward, a stream story can have a maximum of one action link, and 25 characters in the link."

Comment: had exactly the same problem.

Comment: Same problem, hours lost because of this freaking "JSON-encoded array" description. Thanks for your answer.