# How to use a JSON-encoded dictionary of value pairs in Android for Facebook POST "actions" field?

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use my Android app to post to the user timeline but I'm stuck with in the part where I have to add the "actions" field. I'm getting this error from Facebook:

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) actions should be a JSON-encoded dictionary with "name" and "link" keys}
```

And surprisingly enough, there's nothing about it on Google regarding Android.

I can add one action like this and it works:

```
    JSONObject actionAndroid = new JSONObject();
    try {
        actionAndroid.put("name", "Example");
        actionAndroid.put("link","http://www.example.com");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    other params...
    params.putString("actions", actionAndroid.toString());
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```

But I need to add more than one action and I can not make the Object[ ]

[THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish) is where Facebook explains how the "actions" work. But of course, there are no examples or android explanations about the "actions" field.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You're getting errorType: OAuthException. That seems to indicate that something is going wrong with your oauth token. Is your token is working for other methods?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible (having multiple custom action links). I'm clarifying this internally to reflect this in our docs.

Comment: Yes hungryghost, my token is working fine. I can publish with no problem with only one item. I just can't figure the format for more than one item. And ifaour I believe it is, because its description says "actions" and expects an Object[ ]. Otherwise it would just be like "privacy" which expects just an Object.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275428/more-action-links-in-single-wallpost) it is possible to post only one action even though on Facebook's description it says an Array.

But anyway, actions are deprecated since July 2015.